# How do I 'Autofill' a CreateView field

Tags: python, django

I have a model called Artist, and now I'm working on building a comment section for the Artist DetailView.

I've built a model called ArtistComment, created a CreateView and added this to the DetailView using modal divs so it looks nicer. The only issue is that when you click 'add comment' the modal shows both the 'artist' and the 'comment' fields. The artist field is a dropdown menu to select which artist the comment is applied to. I would like to be able to hide the 'artist' field, and have this auto-complete based on the page you follow the 'add comment' link from.

I've managed to get the 'User' field to autocomplete with 'self.request.user' but whenever I try anything like self.request.artist_id it makes my modal form show blank. Can anyone help point me in the right direction to fix this issue?

views.py:

```
class ArtistCommentCreate(CreateView):
    model = ArtistComment
    fields = ['artist', 'message',]

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('events:artistdetail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.artist_id})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super(ArtistCommentCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^artist-(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(views.ArtistDetailView.as_view()), name='artistdetail'),
url(r'^artistcomment/add/$', login_required(views.ArtistCommentCreate.as_view()), name='artistcomment-add'),
```

artistdetail.html:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#artistcommentModal" href="{% url 'events:artistcomment-add' %}">Add A New Comment</a>

<div id="artistcommentModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide artist field remove `artist` from fields.

To get artist in `ArtistCommentCreate` views rewrite url as below:

```
  url(r'^(?P<artist>\d+)/artistcomment/add/$', login_required(views.ArtistCommentCreate.as_view()), name='artistcomment-add'),
```

and in your detail html:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#artistcommentModal" href="{% url 'events:artistcomment-add' artist= artist.id%}">Add A New Comment</a>
```

in your comment view get artist pk as `self.kwargs.get('artist')`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I'm almost there! I'm just having some issue with the comment view, would I be adding the `self.kwargs.get('artist')` to the form_valid like this;  `from.instance.artist = self.kwargs.get('artist')`

Comment: @J_Clique you have to save the form with `commit=False` then in the obj returned will be be a instance of `ArtistComment` and then you can set artist value as: `comment.artist = self.kwargs.get('artist')` , then save comment instance.

Comment: @J_Clique if you find this answer helpful up-vote and accept it.