# Passing a Primary Key to a form template

Tags: python, django, primary-key

This is an update from this questions, which I will amend if I find a complete answer for this issue - [How do I 'Autofill' a CreateView field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586412/how-do-i-autofill-a-createview-field/46606204#46606204)

I have a Artist model, and I'm now trying to add a comment feature to the DisplayView using an ArtistComment modal and a CreateView form on a modal div. I think I'm really close to getting this to work, but I'm having a little issue passing the primary key from my `artistdetail.html` page to my `artistcomment_form.html` template. Any help with this, or tips for documentation pages to read would be greatly appreciated.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^artist-(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(views.ArtistDetailView.as_view()), name='artistdetail'),
url(r'^artist-(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/artistcomment/add/$', login_required(views.ArtistCommentCreate.as_view()), name='artistcomment-add'),
```

views.py:

```
class ArtistCommentCreate(CreateView):
    model = ArtistComment
    fields = ['message',]

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('events:artistdetail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.artist_id})

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.artist = get_object_or_404(Artist, id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return super(ArtistCommentCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

artistdetail.html:

```
<p id="commentfooter"><a href="{% url 'events:artistcomment-add' artist.id %}">Add A New Comment</a></p>
```

artistcomment_from.html:

```
{% block body %}
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'events:artistcomment-add' pk %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="CloseModal();">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% include "events/form-template.html" %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

As far as I can tell, where I've entered 'pk' in my `artistcomment_form.html` is where I am supposed to be referencing the primary key that is stored in the URL. I've tried various combinations of artist.id artist.artistid artist.pk but these are blind guesses that are getting me nowhere. Could anyone help explain what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is:

```
class ArtistCommentCreate(CreateView):
# ...

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArtistCommentCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['pk'] = # Whatever you want to add here (e.g. self.object.artist_id)
        return context
```

Better load the whole artist model as a whole into your context and add a template (artistcomment.html) in your CreateView as it requires one. I think it's possible to load the view with an iFrame or so (I have never tried that) into your page as a popup. 
Also, you don't need to fill the "action" field in your comment form then.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've now added the `get_context_data` part to my ArtistComment CreateView like you described, and removed the 'action' field from my comment form;

 `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
  context = super(ArtistCommentCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
  context['pk'] = self.object.artist_id
  return context`


But I'm now receiving a 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'artist_id' message. I'm assuming it's stemming from the `context['pk'] = self.object.artist_id` but I'm not sure what the correction to this would be. Can you help any further?

Comment: Well, if you want to obtain the Primary Key, you just have to do something like: `context['author'] = self.object`. Then, in the templates you call: `{{ object.pk }}`which returns the Primary Key of your Model instance that you specified in the CreateView. If you have a look at the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview), you can see the inheriting classes of CreateView which should give you an idea of  how that view handles data. Hope that helps!